# Searching Xcode Storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I just spent hours debugging an `"unrecognized selector sent to instance"` runtime error in  IOS.

As it turns out, the unrecognized selector was an erroneous Sent Event within a storyboard referencing a selector that I had since changed in a ViewController.

I used the  `"Show the Search Navigator"` tool to search the source code for the unrecognized selector and could not find it.  Obviously (now) the error was in the storyboard.

Is there a good way to search the storyboard for text that may provide clues to code bugs?

Comment: @Abizern : Sorry I didn't gone through the question properly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Search Navigator within Xcode would not have found that unrecognized selector, since as you stated you had changed the name of that selector already, and the Search Navigator won't search the contents of your storyboards.

Right-click the storyboard file in Xcode and choose *Open As > Source Code*. (**Edit**: originally I instructed to open the storyboard file in an external text editor, but that's not necessary). Use Cmd-F to search the XML for the old selector name. You will be looking for an XML element named `action` with a `selector` attribute equal to the unrecognized selector.

Once you find that, inspect the parent XML elements to get an idea of where this connection is in your storyboard.

Comment: Thanks @esker - my first question on stackoverflow and I get the correct answer in an hour!  I will use this technique until the Search Navigator scope includes the storyboard XML - which seems easy to implement to me.